# Matrix multiplier is not working

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to design a matrix multiplier in Verilog using systolic array architecture. If I test the Processing Elements they work but when trying to connect them to build the array they get the inputs but don't generate the output.

PE test:

[image: PE test]

Systolic array test:
[image: terminal]
[image: waves]

Here is my code:

```
 `timescale 1 ns/ 1 ps

module sys_array_tb;

reg reset, clk;
localparam  M = 2;
localparam  N = 2;
localparam  DW = 16;

reg start;
reg signed [DW-1:0] W [M*N-1:0];
reg signed [DW-1:0] X [M*N-1:0];
wire signed [DW*2:0] Y [M*N-1:0];
wire done;

systolic_array #(.M(M),.N(N), .DW(DW)) uut(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), 
                                    .start(start), .X(X),.W(W),.done(done), .Y(Y));

initial begin
  reset <= 1;
  clk <= 0;
  #3
  reset <= 0;
  #3
  
  

  W = {16'h1, 16'h2, 16'h3, 16'h4};
  X = {16'h1, 16'h2, 16'h3, 16'h4};
  
  start = 1;
  #10


  wait(done);
  
  #3

  W = {16'sh1, 16'sh2, 16'sh3, 16'sh4};
  X = {16'h1, 16'h2, 16'h3, 16'h4};
  
  
  wait(done);
  
  #3

  W = {-16'sh1, -16'sh2, -16'sh3, -16'sh4};
  X = {-16'sh1, -16'sh2, -16'sh3, -16'sh4};
  

  wait(done);
  
  #3

  W = {-16'sh1, 16'h2, 16'h3, -16'sh4};
  X = {16'h1, -16'sh2, -16'sh3, 16'h4};
  
   
  wait(done);

end

initial begin
  repeat(100)
    #5 clk <= ~clk;
end

/*
always @(posedge clk) begin

$display("output is = %h " uut.pe.mac);

end
*/

initial begin
    $dumpfile("wave.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, sys_array_tb);
end



endmodule


module systolic_array #(
    parameter M = 4,
    parameter N = 4,
    parameter DW = 16
)
(
  input clk,
  input reset,
  input start,
  output reg done,
  
  input signed [DW-1:0] W [M*N-1:0],
  input signed [DW-1:0] X [M*N-1:0],
  output signed [2*DW:0] Y [M*N-1:0]
);


reg calc_done;

reg signed [DW-1:0] A_reg [M-1:0][N-1:0];
reg signed [DW-1:0] B_reg [M-1:0][N-1:0];
reg signed [2*DW:0] C_reg [M-1:0][N-1:0]; 

wire [DW-1:0] a_ins [M-1:0][N:0];
wire [DW-1:0] b_ins [M:0][N-1:0];
wire [2*DW:0] c_outs [M-1:0][N-1:0];



integer m,n;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(reset) begin
    m = 0;
    n = 0 ;
    calc_done = 0;
    done = 0;
    //  count <= 0;
    for(m=0;m<=M;m=m+1) begin
      for(n=0;n<=N;n=n+1) begin
        A_reg[m][n] = 16'd0;
        B_reg[m][n] = 16'd0;
        C_reg[m][n] = 33'd0;
        end 
      end 
  end
  else begin
    if (start) begin
      for(m=0;m<=M;m=m+1) begin
        for(n=0;n<=N;n=n+1) begin
          A_reg[m][n] = W[(2*m)+n];
          B_reg[m][n] = X[(2*m)+n];
          C_reg[m][n] = 33'd0;
        end 
      end

      if(!calc_done) begin
        C_reg[m][n] = c_outs[m][n];
        if(n == N) begin
          n = 0;
            if (m == M) begin
              m = 0;
              calc_done = 1;
            end
            else m = m + 1;
        end
        else n = n + 1;       
      end else if(calc_done) begin
        for(m=0;m<=M;m=m+1) begin   //run through the rows
          for(n=0;n<=N;n=n+1) begin    //run through the columns
            Y[(2*m)+n] = C_reg[m][n];
            //Y[m][n] = C_reg[m][n];
          end
        end   
        done = 1; 
      end

    end    
  end
end



genvar  i,j;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i+1) begin : Rows
    for (j = 0; j < N; j = j+1) begin : Columns
      //if(i == M-1 || j == N-1) begin
      //end  
      PE #(.DW(DW)) pe (
        .clk(clk),
        .reset(reset),
        .x_i(a_ins[i][j]),
        .y_i(b_ins[i][j]),
        .x_o(a_ins[i][j+1]),
        .y_o(b_ins[i+1][j]),
        .mac(c_outs[i][j])
      );
    end
  end
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i +1) begin : Left
     assign  a_ins[i][0] = A_reg[i][0];
  end
  for (j = 0; j < N; j = j +1) begin : Top
     assign b_ins[0][j] = B_reg[0][j];
  end
  
endgenerate

endmodule

module PE #(
    parameter DW = 16
)
(
input clk,
input reset,

input signed[DW-1:0] x_i,
input signed[DW-1:0] y_i,

output reg signed[DW-1:0] x_o,
output reg signed[DW-1:0] y_o,
output reg signed[2*DW:0] mac

);


reg signed[DW-1:0] x_reg,y_reg;
reg signed[2*DW:0] mac_reg;

wire signed [2*DW:0] multiply;
assign multiply = x_i * y_i;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
  if (reset) begin
    
    x_reg <= 0;
    y_reg <= 0;  
    mac_reg <= 0;
  end 
  else begin

    x_reg <= x_i;
    y_reg <= y_i;

    mac_reg <= mac_reg + multiply;
    $display ("time: %t, x = %d, y = %d ,mac is %d", $time ,x_i,y_i,mac);
  end
end

assign x_o = x_reg;
assign y_o = y_reg; 
assign mac = mac_reg;
endmodule
```

And as you might noticed the value of `16'h1` never fed to the inputs. Could you please tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What input signal do you mean?  W and X both get a 1 at time=6ns.

Comment: @toolic you mean in the testbench? I noticed from the waves and the terminal that x and y are not getting the 1.

Answer (score 2):

`systolic_array` uses synchronous reset. The reset is disabled before it can be observed on the clock edge. `PE` uses asynchronous reset, so it will observe the reset.

You needed to extend the reset to be at least one clock. I would recommend changing all the `#3` in your test bench to `@(posedge clk)`.

In `systolic_array` you are mixing blocking and non-blocking assignments. There are places that are at risk of a simulation race condition. Flops should be assigned with non-blocking. Everything else should be assigned with blocking.

Consider adding `%m` to your `$display` statement. It will print the hierarchy which can help with debugging.